# Undefined reference to (itpp library)

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker

So I have a problem that I cannot solve by myself (currently still thinking it through). So I've downloaded g++ and it++ libraries for my project and I've chosen Eclipse as my IDE. Everything worked fine, but then I had to overwrite some files in itpp directory (usr/include/itpp). After doing that I had around 100+ errors all saying "undefined reference to ..." and all of them seems to be coming from the files that were added to the library and I really need them. I've tried removing and downloading everything again, but it doesn't seem to work. It seems to be a linker problem and I'm pretty new to linking and stuff(didn't need it in the past) and I'm not to sure how to do it. As far as I can see, in the main .h file of itpp everything seems to be fine, every new .h file has been included and all of the added files are in the right folder. I hope I've made my point clear, but as my English is imperfect you might have some troubles with understanding my problems - if so please state it and I will make myself more clear.

Thanks in advance for any help!

@Edit:

After adding the command "g++ magisterka.cpp $(pkg-config --libs itpp)" under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler, I'm left with only one error and that is make*** [src/name.o] Error 1, but I guess that's a problem to discuss in another thread.

@Edit2:

After all my solution was bad. Maybe all errors disappeared, but it was due to the fact that the command line I've mentioned above was wrong and the new error has occured due to the fact that it could not localize magisterka.cpp which is my main file. Therefore I have now 100 errors again. Will try to post a solution as soon as I get one.

@Edit3: Console

make all 
Building file: ../src/CodeInstance.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -MMD -MP -MF"src/CodeInstance.d" -MT"src/CodeInstance.d" -o "src/CodeInstance.o" "../src/CodeInstance.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/CodeInstance.cpp

Building file: ../src/magisterka.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -MMD -MP -MF"src/magisterka.d" -MT"src/magisterka.d" -o "src/magisterka.o" "../src/magisterka.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/magisterka.cpp

Building target: magisterka
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/include/itpp  -o "magisterka"  ./src/CodeInstance.o ./src/magisterka.o   -litpp
./src/magisterka.o: In function `main':